# Where Are the Items for "076 The Young Alchemist"?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

In order to complete this errand you need one of each:

- Flint Dagger
- Emberstone

Where can these be found?  I'm guessing the emberstone is either found or dropped near / at the Old Smokey volcano, but rather than wander around I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually Errand 76.

You can get Emberstones from slaying monsters around Shimmering Sands.

The Flint Dagger is sold in Al-Mamoon (from Cawtermaster for 240g).

Comment: Thanks, I've made the title edit. Which monsters in particular drop the emberstones?

Comment: Small Fry and Sunshine should drop them. I believe the Crohawks on the island right after you leave Castaway Cove drop them, too. You can also get them by stealing. The Telling Stone under the Creature Compendium tells you what each creature drops.